# Why calendar show Chinese date by using angular6.0+ calendar and angularx-flatpickr

Tags: angular-calendar

I'm following this [demo](https://angular-calendar.com/) to add a calendar in my project, but it shows Chinese date type in calendar instead of English type.

And I have tried the dateFormat,

```
            dateFormat="l, F j, Y TH:i"
            altFormat="F j, Y H:i"
```

but it didn't work.